# How to get a screenshot of the View (Drawing View) used for drawing using UIBezeir path

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layer, uibezierpath

I have a Drawing View which is on a Scroll View. After drawing is completed I need a screenshot of the drawing which I will be uploading to the server.

I am using UIBezeir path to draw on the view.

```
let path = UIBezierPath()

     for i in self.drawView.path{

            path.append(i)

        }
```

self.drawView.path is an NSArray with all the bezeir paths of the drawing.

But when I use the bounding box of this path and get max and min values of coordinates and try to capture a screenshot I get this

```
var rect:CGRect = CGRect(x: path.bounds.minX, y: path.bounds.minY, width: path.bounds.maxX, height: path.bounds.maxY)
```

[image]

I also tried to give the bounds of the path itself

```
let rect:CGRect = CGRect(x: path.bounds.origin.x - 5, y: path.bounds.origin.y - 5, width: path.bounds.size.width + 5, height: path.bounds.size.height + 5)
```

Just for reference I tried using this rect and create a view (clear color with border layer) and placed it over the Drawing, it work pretty fine but when I try to capture an image it goes out of bounds[image]

This is the function I am using to capture the screen

```
func imgScreenShot(bounds:CGRect) -> UIImage{

        let rect: CGRect = bounds
        self.drawView.isOpaque = false
        self.drawView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        var context: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        if let aContext = context {
            self.drawView.layer.render(in: aContext)
        }
        var capturedImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        //let finalImage = scaleImage(image: capturedImage)

        return capturedImage!


    }
```

I am also tried getting a UIView with this function

```
let vw = self.drawView.resizableSnapshotView(from: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true, withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)
```

This gives me a perfect UIView with the drawing in that, but again when I try to convert the UIView to UIImage using the function giving the views bounds, I get a blank image.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or any other solution for how I can get this, bounds of image starting right exactly at the bounds of the drawing

```
let vw = self.drawView.resizableSnapshotView(from: rect2, afterScreenUpdates: true, withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)
            vw?.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
            vw?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            vw?.layer.borderWidth = 1
            self.drawView.addSubview(vw!)
            let image = vw?.snapshotImage
            let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
            imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            self.drawView.addSubview(imgView)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Make an extension of UIView and UIImage** , so in whole **application lifecycle** you can use those methods(which one i will be describe at below) **for capture the screenshort of any perticular UIView and resize the existing image(*if needed*).**

Here is the **extension** of **UIView** :-

```
extension UIView {

    var snapshotImage : UIImage? {

        var snapShotImage:UIImage?

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)

        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

            self.layer.render(in: context)

            if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                snapShotImage = image
            }
        }
        return snapShotImage
    }
}
```

Here is the **extension** of **UIImage** :-

```
extension UIImage {

    func resizeImage(newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage? {

        var newImage:UIImage?

        let horizontalRatio = newSize.width / size.width
        let verticalRatio = newSize.height / size.height

        let ratio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)

        let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)

        if let _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

            draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))

            if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {

                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                newImage = image
            }
        }

        return newImage
    }
}
```

***How to use those functions in our desired class ?***

```
if let snapImage = yourUIView.snapshotImage {

            ///... snapImage is the desired image you want and its dataType is `UIImage`.

           ///... Now resize the snapImage into desired size by using this one 

         if let resizableImage = snapImage.resizeImage(newSize: CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 150.0)) {


            print(resizableImage)
        }

        }
```

here **yourUIView** means , the one you have taken for drawing some inputs. it can be **IBOutlet** as well as your UIView (which you have taken **programmatically**)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, trying the extensions, will update you with the output.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7pWi7.   Still not working , please see the both the images I posted there, this is my code. Please check my edited question I added the code I tried according to your suggestion

Comment: ok will you update soon . the code i have written is perfectly right and working also . but i think when you are going to resize the view something went wrong there . may be scale is going to be bigger thats why you are getting the blank image.

Comment: @SritejaC , is that okay to get the snapShort Image first and after that you could reSize it ?

Comment: I just need an image of any size / scale but with the bounds exactly as shown in the last image of my question.

Comment: @SritejaC , have you tried out it ? first capture the screenshort and after that reSize it .

Comment: How can I resize the image ?

Comment: @SritejaC , okay update the my answer so you can resize the image as well as.

Comment: Yes please, that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Nope still no luck, getting an empty image :/

Comment: @SritejaC , please used the my 2 methods of two extensions , it will definitely work. i have also checked and its already a working code.

Comment: Yeah thank you, will update you after giving it one more go.